# HTML - Hide an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

How do I hide an iframe, but still load it? Etc. For playing a youtube song.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/X18mUlDddCc?autoplay=1" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

This will hide the iframe, however it dosen't seems to load the iframe. (Song is not playing.)

Thanks

Comment: use width 0 in style!

Comment: Yeah because videos do not autoplay. It is a bad practice and you are totally doing this wrong using a youtube video to play songs, are you aware that Youtube will tend to play commercial? how are your visitors going to turn that off? But I edited one of the answers here to at least answer you in context.

Comment: `?autoplay=1` has been disabled in the latest version of Chrome for iframes so this question and answer are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 38):

Use can use width: 0; height: 0; position: absolute; and border: 0;

So the updated code will be!

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/X18mUlDddCc?autoplay=1" style="position: absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0;"></iframe>
```

**Added:**

`style="position: absolute; width:0; height:0; border:0;"`

It will hide it, make media to play in the background and it will also collapse it space!

**Updated Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/ygkvbphs/

Comment: Can you please explain this more

Comment: The little dot is the problem.

Comment: I can see this iframe taking up space if I edit the fiddle to add an element above and below it.

Comment: put the additional CSS code of  `display:none !important`  in there

Comment: if you have `border: none`, you don't need `border: 0`, `0` is overwritten by `none`.

Comment: Updated to fix the spacing issue. @DanBut

Comment: REACT alternative: `style={{position: "absolute", width:0, height:0, border: "none"}}`

Answer (score 14):

I was still having trouble with the iframe taking up space until I added absolute positioning. Then it stopped taking up space all together.

`<iframe src="/auth/sso/" style="width: 0; height: 0; border: 0; border: none; position: absolute;"></iframe>`

Comment: This is the winning answer. position: absolute; made all the difference.

Answer (score 7):

Set the visibility to hidden. However the space it took up won't collapse.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/X18mUlDddCc?autoplay=1" style="visibility: hidden;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 7):

The existing answers using CSS didn't work for me. Even with `display:none` I ended up with a 4x4 dot where the iframe was. What I had to do was the following:

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/X18mUlDddCc?autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

By combining both answers, I use `height:0;` and `visibility:0`, as this works to hide any borders or box shadows as well.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set a `style` of `"display: none;"`.

```
<iframe src="your url" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to position the iframe off the page and out of the way. This won't leave a dot or any trace of the frame.

```
<iframe style="position: absolute; left: -900000px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/X18mUlDddCc?autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the src from iframe then add it back in - forced iframe to load:**

```
 /**
 * Issue: iframe doesn't show because it's in a div that is display:none on load
 *
 * Solution: When the button is clicked to show the hidden div:
 *           in the iframe, copy the url from the src attribute
 *           then set the src attribute to ""
 *           then set the src attribute back to its original value.
 *           This forces the iframe to load.
 */

$('#show-div-button').click(function() {

    var iframe = $('iframe');
    var iframe_src = iframe.attr('src');

    iframe.attr('src', '');
    iframe.attr('src', iframe_src);
});
```