# jquery hide function not working on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm creating a popup which has an iframe to display content from some other website:

```
<div id="popup-wrapper">
  <div id="iframe-wrapper">
    <iframe id="register-frame" src="some url" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want this to be hidden by default and show up when user clicks a button, here's my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#popup-wrapper").hide();
  $("#iframe-wrapper").hide();
  $("#register-frame").hide();
});
```

Both the outer divs disappear but the iframe does not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://validator.nu/ will highlight a fairly obvious error in your HTML

Comment: You need to also set the sizes to 0 as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435089/html-hide-an-iframe/25435121

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML - Hide an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435089/html-hide-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

i have no error when i close the tag iframe, your syntax is not good

```
<iframe id="register-frame" src="some url"></iframe>
```